# Would a PCB thermo handle a high power LED?

Tags: pcb-design, thermal

I need to have my Cree T6 5 W LED on the star, on top of my Arduino shield, would that resist the LED heat?

I plan to use [thermal adhesive](https://thesaberarmory.com/products/20mm-led-star-thermal-adhesive-pad-for-lightsaber-led) and custom make my shield so is 2 sided, with thermal vias arrays and no coating.

Would that be ok, to stick the LED star on top of the shield PCB?

[image: shield+ledStar]

Please note the blue PCB is just for a reference on what I want to do, as commenter I want to make my own PCB for this one.

Comment: Did you reference the datasheet for the LED assembly?  That may say if the assembly requires additional heat sinking. It may also specify if the LED operating parameters need to be derated at higher temperatures (for example if heat sinking is less than ideal).

Comment: What is mounted on your blue PCB? How hot does the LED assembly get?

Comment: @winny thanks, that is just for an example of what I want, my pcb will be custom made, as mentioned 2 layers, with thermal Vias and no coating

Comment: Bare LED or LED module as shown? Are you driving it with 10 W? If yes, it's not possible without fan cooling.

Comment: To dissipate 10W that small aluminum plate is not enough. Additional heatsink should be used. Overwise the LED will be overheating.

Comment: @user263983 5w or 3w would be ok? thanks!

Comment: @manuelBetancurt no it won't by itself – you basically need to achieve the ability to always lose 3W in heat; or the board will logically have to continue to rise in temperature. We can't know how much power you can lose through your board. For that, one would have to know the color of the board, the size of the board, the environmental temperature, the maximum temperature of the board you want to allow, and whether or not there is forced air flow. Or any air flow at all – if you put this in an air-tight container, then that container will become an oven.

Comment: Another thing: I really don't know *why* you chose to put that photo of a blue board behind that LED, that makes no sense to me (the relative dimensions of board and LED seem to be off as well, so this is more confusing than helpful), but if you are planning to power your board from the Arduino, you will have a problem: an Arduino cannot provide that power.

Comment: This is what thermal analysis tools are for.

Comment: LEDs made by reputable companies have part numbers rather than wattages in the name. "Cree T6 5 W LED" has no part number and is probably not really made by Cree or actually 5W if you're buying it on Amazon/eBay. Buying high efficiency LEDs would make a lot of sense here, the best LEDs can convert half the supply power into light, which means way less heatsink required for the same brightness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick and dirty answer...

Suppose ambient temperature is 30°C, and maximum LED chip temperature is 100°C That's already quite high and will reduce LED life ; 60-70°C would be better.

That's a 70°C delta T between LED chip and ambient, at 5W this means we need a total thermal resistance of 70/5 = 14°C/W.

Thermal resistance junction to board:

- Cree XML: 2.5°C/W
- Cree XML2: 0.75°C/W

Thermal transfer through the insulating dielectric between the pad and the star MCPCB aluminium core: 1-1.5°C/W for

Through the star MCPCB aluminium core, thermal grease, and to the heatsink: about 0.5°C/W

So we have a rough estimate of the total thermal resistance between the LED chip and the heat sink, at 2.25-4.5°C/W. That depends on XLM vs XML2, star PCB dielectric parameters, etc.

That's taken out of our 14°C/W budget, so we need a 10-12°C/W heat sink.

Using [this tool](https://www.heatsinkcalculator.com/pcb-temperature-calculator.html) a 4x5cm PCB, double sided, all copper, with vias, results in 20°C/W which is not adequate.

In addition a horizontal PCB benefits much less from convection than a vertical heat sink. If the board is inside an enclosure, airflow will be much worse.

A much better solution would be to mount the LED on a proper heat sink (here's [an example](https://fr.rs-online.com/web/p/dissipateurs-de-chaleur/6744844?cm_mmc=FR-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-CSS_FR_FR_PMAX_Catch%20All-_--_-6744844&matchtype=&&gad_source=1)). This also allows the user to place the LED wherever they want. I selected a pin fin heat sink because they work better in most orientations, whereas flat fin heat sink really want air convection to go in the direction of the fins.

In commercially available low power (<20W) LED lights, the enclosure is the heat sink. This isn't easy to do in small quantities.